# EF - Navigation property explanation

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I use EF 4 and Membership Provider Shipped with ASP.Net 4.0.

I need find all Users in a Specific Role and Populate a DropDownList using `List<ListItem>`.

DataBase Tables involved  are:

```
aspnet_Roles
aspnet_Users
aspnet_UsersInRoles
```

Navigation Property from aspnet_Users to aspnet_Roles (using junction table aspnet_UsersInRoles) is:

```
myUser.aspnet_Roles
```

Matching RoleID (Guid) "CE44ED48-E9F9-49C6-9E15-E40EEFDC7479")

My Script:

```
        using (CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel context = new CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel())
        {
            IQueryable<aspnet_Users> userQuery = from aspnet_Users in context.aspnet_Users select aspnet_Users;
            IQueryable<aspnet_Roles> roleQuery = from aspnet_Roles in context.aspnet_Roles select aspnet_Roles;
            List<ListItem> myListUsersInRoles = new List<ListItem>();
            foreach (aspnet_Users myUser in userQuery)
            {
            // PROBLEM HERE
            if (myUser.aspnet_Roles.ToString() == "CE44ED48-E9F9-49C6-9E15-E40EEFDC7479")
                myListUsersInRoles.Add(new ListItem(myUser.UserName.ToString(), myUser.UserId.ToString()));

            uxListUsers.DataSource = myListUsersInRoles;
            uxListUsers.DataBind();
        }`
```

Problems:
IF return FALSE always, so I am not able to populate List<>.
I suppose I am doing wrong in if an some Properties.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myUser.aspnet_Roles` is an `EntitySet<aspnet_Roles>` (in other words, a **collection** of roles, so it's highly unlikely that it's string representation happens to match the string representation of the role you're after's ID.

There are several ways you could fix it.  One is:

```
// ...
if (myUser.aspnet_Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId.ToString() == "CE44ED48-E9F9-49C6-9E15-E40EEFDC7479"))
// ...
```

Also note that `from y in x select y` is just the same as `x`, so you could write

```
foreach (aspnet_User myUser in context.aspnet_Users)
// ...
```

And not bother declaring `userQuery` or `roleQuery`.  (You don't actually seem to be using `roleQuery` anywhere anyway...)

Also, you could look at using the membership/roles API to fetch users in a role:

```
using System.Web.Security; // at the top of your file
var usersInRole = Roles.GetUsersInRole("name of role here, NOT the guid");
```

Note that this returns an array of usernames, not user objects, so you'd have to do a little extra work to get the User ID, but it is something you could think about...

Comment: Thanks John for your explanation. Finally I understood how does it works. I used if (myUser.aspnet_Roles.Any(r => r.RoleName == "CMS-AUTHOR")) and it is working great! I will also try with using System.Web.Security as you sad.. Thanks very much once again for your help!

Comment: Sorry John,last thing... could you tell me a common example of use for IQueryable<>?? I am a really beginner. thanks!